# Apply same effect multiple times?

Tags: xna, shader

I have encountered a problem which I can't solve. I have to draw a texture while using the same effect multiple times. I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(); 

// Use the effect multiple times with a different parameter:
lightEffect.Parameters["parameter"].SetValue(value1);
lightEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();      
lightEffect.Parameters["parameter"].SetValue(value2);
lightEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();                                        

spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);

spriteBatch.End();
```

Only the second effect is used. That is why I decided to redraw the RenderTarget to itself multiple times using the effect each time, but that also fails miserably, because `"The render target must not be set on the device when it is used as a texture"`.

```
graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(tempRenderTarget);

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(0,0), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();           

foreach (Value value in values)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);            

    lightEffect.Parameters["paramter"].SetValue(value);
    lightEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();                    

    spriteBatch.Draw(tempRenderTarget, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);

    spriteBatch.End();  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use two alternating render targets:

```
RenderTarget input;
RenderTarget output;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPasses; i++)
{
    // Bind the target that is currently the output
    graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(output);

    // Use the current input target as texture in your effect
    // ...

    // Swap input and output
    RenderTarget temp = input;
    input = output;
    output = temp;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I get the black screen after drawing the RenderTarget on the screen, just for testing, but that is a totally different story :D.